# Storage event not firing

Tags: javascript, local-storage, dom-events

Attaching the event:

```
$(window).on("storage", function (e) {
   //callback not getting hit
});
```

Trying to fire the event:

```
localStorage.setItem("test", "123");
```

I have two tabs open, both listening to the storage event. I can see the localStorage getting updated correctly on both tabs. However when I change localStorage on one tab, the other never fires the event. Any ideas?

Tried on Chrome/Firefox. Domain format is `https://www.xxx.yyy.zzz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was caused by `document.domain` overriding in code. After I removed the `document.domain` setter, events worked correctly.

Seems this is caused by a bug in Chrome.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=136356&q=label%3AOWP-Standards-Compatibility&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Comment: `After I removed the offending line, events worked correctly.` which offending line did you removed?

Comment: I rephrased the answer, is it more clear now? I had `document.domain = xyz.com` on a page with host `abc.xyz.com`.

Answer (score 62):

As others in the answers noted, the `storage` event only get picked up  (by the listener) if the *localStorage* was changed in another browser's tab/window (of the same app), but **not** within the context of the current tab.

#### Detect storage changes in the *current tab*:

```js
window.addEventListener('storage', console.log)

window.localStorage.setItem('test', '123')
window.dispatchEvent( new Event('storage') ) // <-----
```

A manual `storage` event is dispatched.

This will effectively trigger the `storage` event listener *twice* on other tabs/windows (of the same app), but in certain situations this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Simply awesome :)

Answer (score 56):

StorageEvent is fired in different page with the same domain.

> From MDN
>
> The StorageEvent is fired whenever a change is made to the Storage object.
>
> This won't work on the same page that is making the changes — it is really a way for other pages on the domain using the storage to sync any changes that are made。

Answer (score 10):

An additional point to [vsync's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65348883/807838) is you can fire [`StorageEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageEvent) instead of `Event` and pass in an object so the fired event will match the browser default.

```js
const oldValue = window.localStorage.getItem('test');
window.localStorage.setItem('test', newValue);
const event = new StorageEvent('storage', {
  key: 'test',
  oldValue,
  newValue,
  ...
});

window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Answer (score 4):

If even testing between different tabs/pages and still not seeing the event... I've found that the event will only fire if the key already exists.

It seems it's more like an `onchange` event.

Set a default value to the `localStorage` key, if even `undefined` and then test.

I'd call this a Chrome bug, as Firefox and Safari are firing correctly, but it is what it is.

Comment: 2022 i've up-voted and can confirm this,

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function (e) {
      console.log("storage event occured here");
},false);
```

Storage Listner get called in other tabs , other than source tab. Just add debugger to other tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a utility like [localDataStorage](https://github.com/macmcmeans/localDataStorage) to fire the events for you, in the same window/tab, whenever a key value changes, such as those made by the set or remove methods. You can also use it to transparently set/get any of the following "types": Array, Boolean, Date, Float, Integer, Null, Object or String.

[DISCLAIMER] I am the author of the utility [/DISCLAIMER]

Once you instantiate the utility, the following snippet will allow you to monitor the events:

```
function localStorageChangeEvents( e ) {
    console.log(
        "timestamp: "     + e.detail.timestamp + " (" + new Date( e.detail.timestamp ) + ")" + "\n" +
        "key: "           + e.detail.key     + "\n" +
        "old value: "     + e.detail.oldval  + "\n" +
        "new value: "     + e.detail.newval  + "\n"
    );
};
document.addEventListener(
    "localDataStorage"
    , localStorageChangeEvents
    , false
);
```

Comment: That is so unreadable. Could you post the original source code as well in that repo? I'm actually curious what your logic is.

Comment: Point taken, and you're right. I've updated the repo with the source files. 

Comment: was this downvoted for any other reason beyond being unreadable (which has since been fixed)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to logout from other tabs if logged out from one tab. The problem I faced was setting the same value over and over.

Thats why the Storage event not fired in other tabs. A simple hack was to add a salt/random stuff everytime to emit the event.

```js
 window.localStorage.setItem('logout-event',Math.random().toString())
```

Then the events are available in other tabs! A better way to handle events from other tabs is to use [BroadcastChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API)