# Using localstorage in useEffect dependency works, but gives warning

Tags: reactjs

I want to use the localStorage getItem in the useEffect dependency. It works, when I set authorization anywhere in my code, it updates the value, but it gives me warning:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setValue(localStorage.getItem(key))
}, [localStorage.getItem(key)])
```

The warning:

```
React Hook useEffect has a complex expression in the dependency array. Extract it to a separate variable so it can be statically checked
```

What does this mean and how can I extract it. Also I know I can attach listener to localstorage, but can I do it this way?

Answer (score 4):

You can use custom hooks for that

```js
const profile = useProfileData();
```

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function getProfileData() {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));
}

export default function useProfileData() {
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState(getProfileData());

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleChangeStorage() {
      setProfile(getProfileData());
    }

    window.addEventListener('storage', handleChangeStorage);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('storage', handleChangeStorage);
  }, []);

  return profile;
}
```

if you don't get why it's not catched see that question
[Storage event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35865481/storage-event-not-firing)

in summary it's catching events on different pages

Answer (score 3):

`localStorage.getItem(key)` is a complex expression, `useEffect` wants a static simple variable or object to compare, it doesn't want to run code inside that array.

I don't know how the rest of your app is set up, but either pass it through as a prop, or just split it out into a variable to pass into the array.

---

You can alternatively do something like:

```
window.addEventListener('storage', () => setValue(localStorage.getItem(key)));
```

Which will fire when storage is changed.