# React app local storage not updating Menu component in Marvel API app

Tags: reactjs, url-parameters

I created an app using the Marvel API that searches characters, comics, events, series, and creators and displays their information. Everything is working properly except for the Menu.jsx component is not updating to the values that are in local storage. For example, if I search for the character "Wolverine", it sets the local storage "heroName" variable to "Wolverine," but then if I click the logo link or the "Heroes" link again, it doesn't load this "heroName" into the page.

Here is the code in App.jsx:

```
export default function App() {

  return (
    <HashRouter>
      <Menu />
      <Routes>
        {/* Heroes */}
        <Route path={'/:hName'} element={<Home />} />
        <Route exact path={'/characters/:id/comics'} element={<HeroComics />} />
        <Route exact path={'/characters/:id/events'} element={<HeroEvents />} />
        <Route exact path={'/characters/:id/series'} element={<HeroSeries />} />
        <Route exact path={'/characters/:id/stories'} element={<HeroStories />} />
        {/* Comics */}
        <Route exact path={'/comics'} element={<ComicsPage />} />
        {/* Events */}
        <Route exact path={'/events'} element={<EventsPage />} />
        {/* Series */}
        <Route exact path={'/series'} element={<SeriesPage />} />
        {/* Stories */}
        <Route exact path={'/stories'} element={<StoriesPage />} />
        {/* Creators */}
        <Route path={'/creators/:cName'} element={<CreatorsPage />} />
        <Route exact path={'/creators/:id/comics'} element={<CreatorComics />} />
        <Route exact path={'/creators/:id/events'} element={<CreatorEvents />} />
        <Route exact path={'/creators/:id/series'} element={<CreatorSeries />} />
        <Route exact path={'/creators/:id/stories'} element={<CreatorStories />} />
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </HashRouter>
  );
}
```

Here is the code in Menu.jsx:

```
export default function Menu() {

    const [heroName, setHeroName] = useState("");
    const [creatorName, setCreatorName] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        setHeroName(localStorage.getItem('heroName'));
        setCreatorName(localStorage.getItem('creatorName'));
    }, []);

    return (
        <Navbar expand="lg" sticky="top" className="nav-bar">
            <Container>
                <Navbar.Brand as={Link} to={`/${heroName}`} className="logo-text">Marvel App</Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
                <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                    <Nav className="ml-auto">
                        <Nav.Link as={Link} to={`/${heroName}`}>Heroes</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link as={Link} to={"/comics"}>Comics</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link as={Link} to={"/events"}>Events</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link as={Link} to={"/series"}>Series</Nav.Link>
                        {/* <Nav.Link as={Link} to={"/stories"}>Stories</Nav.Link> */}
                        <Nav.Link as={Link} to={`/creators/${creatorName}`}>Creators</Nav.Link>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Container>
        </Navbar>
    )
}
```

Here is how I'm setting and getting local storage in Home.jsx:

```
useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('heroName', hName);
        const heroName = localStorage.getItem('heroName');
        setHeroName(heroName);
        handleClick(heroName);
    }, []);

    const handleShow = async (heroID) => {
        setShow(true);
        try {
            let data = await fetchCharactersByCharacterID(heroID);
            setHero(data.data.results);
        } catch (err) {
            return err;
        }
    }

    const handleClick = async (heroName) => {
        try {
            let data = await fetchCharacters(heroName);
            setHeroes(data.data.results);
            localStorage.setItem('heroName', heroName);
            navigate(`/${heroName}`);
        } catch (err) {
            return err;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I cannot get to reproduce the "problem" you mention at the end of your question... Could you please add the exact steps to get the wrong behavior you're trying to fix?

Comment: @indyteo Search for a character and then click Comics, then click the logo or Heroes again. It should return the character you searched for, but it doesn't.

Comment: Ok I think I understood what your problem is. Modifying the local storage won't update a component by itself, you may use a context to store global information about your app: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context#use-cases-for-context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by getting Menu.jsx to reload on link click. Here is my new code:

```
export default function Menu() {

    const heroName = localStorage.getItem('heroName');
    const creatorName = localStorage.getItem('creatorName');

    let navigate = useNavigate();

    function changeLocation(placeToGo) {
        navigate(placeToGo, { replace: true });
        window.location.reload();
    }

    return (
        <Navbar expand="lg" sticky="top" className="nav-bar">
            <Container>
                <Navbar.Brand as={Link} to={`/${heroName}`} onClick={() => changeLocation(`/${heroName}`)} className="logo-text">Marvel App</Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
                <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                    <Nav className="ml-auto">
                        <Nav.Link as={Link} to={`/${heroName}`} onClick={() => changeLocation(`/${heroName}`)}>Heroes</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link as={Link} to={"/comics"} onClick={() => changeLocation("/comics")}>Comics</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link as={Link} to={"/events"} onClick={() => changeLocation("/events")}>Events</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link as={Link} to={"/series"} onClick={() => changeLocation("/series")}>Series</Nav.Link>
                        {/* <Nav.Link as={Link} to={"/stories"}>Stories</Nav.Link> */}
                        <Nav.Link as={Link} to={`/creators/${creatorName}`} onClick={() => changeLocation(`/creators/${creatorName}`)}>Creators</Nav.Link>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Container>
        </Navbar>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Menu.jsx` you're using `useEffect` only once, when the component is rendering and therefore it's not changing when you change the localStorage value.

Try add `localStorage` to the `useEffect` dependencies.

i.e.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setHeroName(localStorage.getItem('heroName'));
    setCreatorName(localStorage.getItem('creatorName'));

}, [localStorage]); // or localStorage.getItem('heroName')
```

Comment: Be careful that using a complex dependency may give some warnings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62951156/using-localstorage-in-useeffect-dependency-works-but-gives-warning

Comment: @HindicatoR Adding "localStorage" to the dependency didn't help.