# how to change the below lines in javascript to reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Here we have done this coding in javascrpit. How we can change this into reactjs.

```
   localStorage.setItem("actNumber", JSON.stringify(response.data.accountNumbers))
   localStorage.setItem("Token", response.data.accessToken)
   localStorage.setItem("cifNumber", 
   JSON.stringify(response.data.cifNumber).replace(/^"(.*)"$/, '$1'))
```

Comment: Copy, paste, done.

Comment: Yes, this can be done in ReactJS as well

Comment: yes, im doing this using react redux. in action folder i have did this but showing error in localstorage like undefined

Answer (score 0):

localStorage is not working on same page. Use window.dispatchEvent. Please refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35865481/storage-event-not-firing)